Python web scraping via api
I am trying to scrap information from a website (USTA) with Python but failed with 403 responses. The webpage doesn't require any login and I can find the request and response with developer tools in a browser without any issue. For example, while accessing this [URL]:
(https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/player-search/profile.html#?uaid=2017185101)
there was one request post to:
https://www.usta.com/usta/api?type=playerInfo 

with header:
dicData= {"selection":{"uaid":2017185101},"output":{"ratings":"true", "wtn":"true", "extendedProfile":"true"}}

I am not sure why my code did not work but there was a Hash header item added during the process via a browser. Any suggestion on solving this issue? Here is my code:
import requests
strURL="https://www.usta.com/usta/api?type=playerInfo"
dicData= {"selection":{"uaid":2017185101},"output":{"ratings":"true", "wtn":"true", "extendedProfile":"true"}}
dicHead = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0", "Accept": "*/*", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
r = requests.post(strURL, dicData, headers=dicHead)
print(r)


I had no issues with the code bellow:
import requests

url = 'https://www.usta.com/usta/api?type=playerInfo'

headers = {
    'hash': '<YOUR_HASH>',
    'referer': 'https://www.usta.com/en/home/play/player-search/profile.html',
    'user-agent': '<YOUR_USER_AGENT>',
}

data = "{\"selection\":{\"uaid\":\"2017185101\"},\"output\":{\"ratings\":\"true\",\"extendedProfile\":\"true\",\"wtn\":\"true\"}}"

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.json())


Thanks for your response. I gave up checking too early :( I tried your code with the hash string obtained from developer tools but got a "Response [400]" error. I also noticed that the hash values change after every page refresh. What did you use for the hash?
